# How to Use jinja to render HTML without flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I need to render HTML page using jinja but without flask I read some other questions here but none had clear answer kindly let me know how can i achieve the same

```
File structre

1.py

HTML folder

1.html

templates
show persons.txt
```

Here I need to render **1.html using 1.py** - is it possble to do it in ofline mode

**current 1.py**

```
  from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

persons = [
    {'name': 'Andrej', 'age': 34},
    {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 17},
    {'name': 'Thomas', 'age': 44},
    {'name': 'Lucy', 'age': 14},
    {'name': 'Robert', 'age': 23},
    {'name': 'Dragomir', 'age': 54}
]

file_loader = FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)

template = env.get_template('show persons.txt')

 
template = env.get_template('1.html ') #  how can i do the same with html here
output = template.render(persons=persons)
print(output)
```

currently with this I am able to print output but if I need to get same data on a html file what can be done here  ?

Also if possible if also can we open the html page when run

updated code after Corralien comments is der a way to open this in browser directly

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

persons = [
    {'name': 'Andrej', 'age': 34},
    {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 17},
    {'name': 'Thomas', 'age': 44},
    {'name': 'Lucy', 'age': 14},
    {'name': 'Robert', 'age': 23},
    {'name': 'Dragomir', 'age': 54}
]

file_loader = FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)

template = env.get_template('1.html')

output = template.render(persons=persons)
print(output)
```

Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Andrej -  34
Mark -  17
Thomas -  44
Lucy -  14
Robert -  23
Dragomir -  54

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want exactly?

Comment: Jinja doesn't have anything to do with offline/online and definitely doesn't require Flask. If you want an html file, then why are you using a txt file? Can you share the template?

Comment: i am currently unaware how to use html in place of text so have added current code

Comment: @Corralien i need to open html file 1.html with persons data dispalyed

Comment: `env.get_template('1.html')`. Jinja doesn't care if you are using a text file or a html file.

Comment: thanks @Corralien it works is there any way i can also open the html file in browser after

Comment: Sure, there is, but you should limit your posts to single questions, please

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks kindly pardon dont want to create a seperate thread here if possible can u kindly guide here have updated question

Comment: I already gave my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open your html file into your browser, use [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module (standard library)

```
import webbrowser
import tempfile

# Your code here
...
output = template.render(persons=persons)

with open('output.html', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(output)
webbrowser.open_new('output.html')  # or .open_new_tab('output.html')
```

Comment: import tempfile ??
NameError: name 'template' is not defined. 
:-(

Comment: @DaveP. Replace the ellipsis (`...`) by the code of the OP. `template = env.get_template('show persons.txt')`

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'template'

Comment: Read the code of OP is complete. My answer concerns only webbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the template already has valid html structure, sounds like you just want to write a file

```
template = env.get_template('show persons.txt')
with open('HTML folder/1.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(template.render(persons=persons))
```

To load the file in the browser, you can try using `os.startfile` method. Otherwise, use a specific browser executable with the `subprocess` module

Comment: currently with @Corralien comment i am able to get html data n print is der anyway i can also open the result in browser adding updated code

Comment: Like I said, `os.startfile` will use the associated OS program to open html files